# CKEditor 4.10 not all toolbar options are being rendered

Tags: ckeditor, config, toolbar

I have multiple CKEditor instances on different pages so I don't want to modify config.js or have a separate instance of config.js for each page.

I'm creating the toolbar at runtime using this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    CKEDITOR.replace('Description');

    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['Description'];
    if (editor) {
        editor.destroy(true);
    }

    CKEDITOR.config.toolbar_Basic = [
        { name: 'document', items: [ 'Source', '-', 'Save', 'NewPage', 'Preview', 'Print', '-', 'Templates' ] },
        { name: 'clipboard', items: [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ] },
        { name: 'editing', items: [ 'Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'Scayt' ] },
        { name: 'forms', items: [ 'Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton', 'HiddenField' ] },
        '/',
        { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'CopyFormatting', 'RemoveFormat' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph', items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl', 'Language' ] },
        { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor' ] },
        { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe' ] },
        '/',
        { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize' ] },
        { name: 'colors', items: [ 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ] },
        { name: 'tools', items: [ 'Maximize', 'ShowBlocks' ] },
        { name: 'about', items: [ 'About' ] }

    ];
    CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = 'Basic';
    CKEDITOR.config.width=650;
    CKEDITOR.config.height=400;
    CKEDITOR.config.extraAllowedContent = 'span;ul;li;table;td;style;*[id];*(*);*{*}';
    CKEDITOR.replace('Description', CKEDITOR.config);

    });
```

Not all my toolbar options are showing up. For instance,

```
    { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize' ] },
    { name: 'colors', items: [ 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ] },
```

Styles and Format are visible but Font, FontSize, TextColor and BGColor are not.

How do I get those missing toolbar items to show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was simply a matter of not having the full CKEditor installed. I installed the standard version which does not contain the font and color plugins.

Installing the full version corrected the situation.